# What are the units of winpcap captured packets, Layer 2 frames or layer 3 packets?

Tags: c++, networking, winpcap

Just a wondering while developing a network traffic inspection program, no context is relevant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It captures the entire Layer 2 frame.  The layer 2 frame contains layers 3-7 PDUs assuming the frame is based on some protocol.

Comment: Oh,thanks. And I am still have a question,that when open the device,the examples given by winpcap developer's pack specified the snap length as 65536, but the max frame size is 1500 bytes.So I think it si by ip packets.

Comment: The maximum *payload* size on *Ethernet* is 1500 bytes.  The snapshot length includes the link-layer header, so, in order to capture a fill Ethernet packet, it would have to be at least 1514 (1518 if captured frames include the CRC).  The example uses 65536 so that it'll work on arbitrary networks, including networks where the maximum link-layer packet size is *larger* then 1514.